# How to update the Mongodb Nodejs driver to the latest version?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, cloud9-ide

I would like to know the easiest way to update the mongodb nodejs driver to the latest version.  I've tried running just `npm install mongodb` but it doesn't seem to update to the most current version of the driver.

Also, I'm using the cloud9 IDE.  Might it be the case that the cloud9 application blocks certain update commands?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did the answer below resolve your issue? If not, can you paste any error messages you might be getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nice package for check and update to latest versions nodejs packages

https://github.com/tjunnone/npm-check-updates

`ncu -u mongodb`

`npm install`